# How to give each user access to their personal folders and block access to others

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using session to store my user information and I want to know how to give access for each user to his private folder of file?

I want that each user will have access to his unique one folder and the manager will have access for whole folder. This can be done by session?

This is User.cs:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public Guid? ResetPasswordCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }

    public Guid ActivationCode { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext Connect to Db:

```
public class DikanDbContext : DbContext {
    public DikanDbContext() : base ("name=DikanNetDB")
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Login Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin loginuser)
    {
        ViewBag.Status = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DikanDbContext ctx = new DikanDbContext())
            {
                var account = ctx.Users.Where(e => e.UserId == loginuser.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (account != null)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(loginuser.Password), account.Password) == 0)
                    {
                        int timeout = loginuser.RememberMe ? 525600 : 120; // one year or 1.5 hour
                        switch (account.Role) // checks the role of the account to direct to their controller
                        {
                            case "Student":
                                if (account.IsEmailVerified) // checks if the student has verify with email
                                {
                                    HttpContext.Session.Add("Student", account);
                                    Session.Timeout = timeout;

                                    var student = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.StudentId == account.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (student != null) // if the account found in student table
                                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
                                    else // not found in student table-> go to fill basic info
                                    {
                                        ViewBag.Status = true;
                                        return RedirectToAction("UpdateStudent","Student");
                                    }
                                }
                                return View();
                            case "Admin":
                                HttpContext.Session.Add("admin",account);
                                Session.Timeout = timeout;
                                return RedirectToAction("Index","Admin");
                            default: break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return View(loginuser);
    }
}
```

> > **Update** - Each user can upload their own file and the files will be saves in file system under UsersFiles-> UserId
> >     If I Write in url the route to other UserId I have the access to their files so, I want to block this operation How I can do that
>
> Files Class:

```
    public static string SaveFileInServer(HttpPostedFileBase pFile, string pFileName, string pId,string pOldFile)
    {
        int fileSize = pFile.ContentLength;
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(pFile.FileName);
        var serverpathsave = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UsersFiles/") + pId);
        if (!Directory.Exists(serverpathsave))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(serverpathsave);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pOldFile))
            File.Delete(Path.Combine(serverpathsave ,pOldFile));
        pFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(serverpathsave, pFileName + fileExt)); // save file to server                                                                      
        return pFileName+fileExt;
    }

    /* The function get a file name and id of student
     * and delete the file from the server database
     */
    public static bool Delete(string pFileName, string pId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pFileName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pId))
            return false;

        var serverpath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UsersFiles/") + pId);
        if (!Directory.Exists(serverpath)) return false;

        File.Delete(Path.Combine(serverpath, pFileName));
        return true;
    }
```

> Picture Of File System each user has folder with his UserId:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BghTx.png)

> Example of adding file to server

```
 public ActionResult UpdateStudent(Student UpdateStudent)
        {
                    if(UpdateStudent.FileId != null)
                        UpdateStudent.PathId = Files.SaveFileInServer(UpdateStudent.FileId, "Id", UpdateStudent.StudentId,(dbStudent == null) ? null:dbStudent.PathId);

                    if (dbStudent == null) // after first login fill more info
                        ctx.Students.Add(UpdateStudent); // add student to data base
                    else
                        ctx.Entry(dbStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(UpdateStudent);// update student
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    if (tempuser != null && tempuser.IsEmailVerified == false) // if the student change the email disconnect from system
                        return RedirectToAction("Disconnect", "Login");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
```

Comment: To answer this question, we need to understand what you mean by 'folder'. Even after looking at the code, I could not understand where the notion of 'folder' fitted. Can you elaborate your question, or perhaps provide more code example?

Comment: Hello friend thanks for commenting, See My Update

Comment: You must use an action method to serve the files. The method can determine the id of the current user, then read and serve the requested files with the `Controller.File(...)` method.

Comment: didnt undetstand can you explain? I have added code of save file in server

Comment: Do not map a virtual path onto the physical folder as you are doing at the moment. There is no way to protect the folder unless you are running IIS and using Basic Authentication. Instead, put the files in another physical location and provide a controller action to serve the files.

Comment: Ok and how to do it in controller?